# SOLR Faceting for special characters

Tags: apache, search, solr, facet, faceted-search

I have multiple languages(English, German, Chinese, Japanese) in my collection and I would like to perform Faceting. Faceting works good for English and German but for chinese and japanese, I am not getting any facets. Can someone help me in solving this ?

```
<fieldType name="text_general_search_ja" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="false">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.JapaneseTokenizerFactory" mode="search"/>
        <filter class="solr.JapaneseBaseFormFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.JapanesePartOfSpeechStopFilterFactory" tags="lang/stoptags_ja.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.CJKWidthFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_ja.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.JapaneseKatakanaStemFilterFactory" minimumLength="4"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Facet field name is **catchall_asia-pacific_cn_zh** and the type for the field name is **text_general_search_ja**. The configuration of text_general_search_ja is mentioned above

Comment: whats the field type used for english and german?

Comment: Use text for facets is not advisable. If you want to achieve both, search on fields and faceting on the field on catchall_asia-pacific_cn_zh then extract it in 2 separate fields, one fields as string field type and another as text and use these for different use cases as required.

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti I use something similar for German as well.Please find the config below.

Comment: <fieldType name="text_general_search_de" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer type="index">
   <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
            <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_de.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
   <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" splitOnCaseChange="0" splitOnNumerics="0" preserveOriginal="1"/>

Comment: For German and English , I have used the text field type and it works good .

Comment: If it works for German and English...its not necessary that it will work for other languages like Chinese or Japanese ...If you ask me below is the ideal thing to do...

Answer (score 0):

Use of text field types for facets is not advisable.

If you want to achieve both, search on fields and faceting on the field on `catchall_asia-pacific_cn_zh` then extract it in 2 separate fields.

One fields as string field type which would be helpful in faceting and sorting.

Second as text field type and use these for search on the fields.

These are 2 different use case and hence would be good to have 2 separate fields.